# using an Audio Endpoint other than 'DefaultAudioEndpoint' in C#

Tags: c#, audio, default, endpoint, cscore

[This program](https://github.com/DarthAffe/KeyboardAudioVisualizer) is an audio visualizer for an `rgb` keyboard that listens to windows' default audio device. My audio setup is a bit more involved, and I use way more than just the default audio device. For instance, when I play music from `Winamp` it goes through the device `Auxillary 1 (Synchronous Audio Router)` instead of `Desktop Input (Synchronous Audio Router)` which I have set as Default. I'd like to be able change the device that the program listens to for the visualization.

I found in the source where the audio device is declared; Lines 32-36 in `CSCoreAudioInput.cs`:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    MMDevice captureDevice = MMDeviceEnumerator.DefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Console);
    WaveFormat deviceFormat = captureDevice.DeviceFormat;
    _audioEndpointVolume = AudioEndpointVolume.FromDevice(captureDevice);
}
```

The way that I understand it from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CoreAudio/mmdevice-api), the section `MMDeviceEnumerator.DefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Console)` is where Windows gives the application my default IMMEndpoint "Desktop Input."

How would I go about changing `DefaultAudioEndpoint`?

[Further Reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mmdeviceapi/nn-mmdeviceapi-immdevice) shows a few ways to get an IMMDevice, with `DefaultAudioEnpoint` being one of them. It seems to me that I'd have to enumerate the devices, and then separate out `Auxillary 1 (Synchronous Audio Router)` using `PKEY_Device_FriendlyName`. That's a bit much for me, as I have little to no `C#` experience. Is there an easier way to go about choosing a different endpoint? Am I on the right track? or am I missing the mark completely?

Also, what is the difference between `MMDevice` and `IMMDevice`? The source only seems to use `MMDevice` while all the Microsoft documentation references `IMMDevice`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I DID IT!

I've found why the program uses `MMDevice` rather than `IMMDevice`. The developer has chosen to use the [CSCore](https://github.com/filoe/cscore) Library rather than Windows' own Core  Audio API.

From continued reading of the [CSCore MMDeviceEnumerator Documentation](https://filoe.github.io/cscore/sharpDox/1.2.0-release/#type/MMDeviceEnumerator), it looks like I'll have to make a separate program that outputs all endpoints and their respective Endpoint ID Strings. Then I can substitute the `DefaultAudioEndpoint` method with the `GetDevice(String id)` method, where `String id` is the ID of whichever Endpoint I chose from the separate program.

To find the the Endpoint I wanted, I wrote this short program to find all the info I wanted:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
        MMDeviceCollection collection = enumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(DataFlow.Render,DeviceState.Active);
        Console.WriteLine($"\nNumber of active Devices: {collection.GetCount()}");

        int i = 0;
        foreach (MMDevice device in collection){

            Console.WriteLine($"\n{i} Friendly name: {device.FriendlyName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Endpoint ID: {device.DeviceID}");
            i++;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

This  showed me that the Endpoint I wanted was item number 3 (2 in an array) on my list, and instead of using `GetDevice(String id)` I used `ItemAt(int deviceIndex)`.

```
MMDeviceEnumerator enumerator = new MMDeviceEnumerator();
MMDeviceCollection collection = enumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints(DataFlow.Render,DeviceState.Active);
MMDevice captureDevice = collection.ItemAt(2);
```

However in this case, the program was not using `captureDevice` to bring in the audio data. These were the magic lines:

```
_capture = new WasapiLoopbackCapture(100, new WaveFormat(deviceFormat.SampleRate, deviceFormat.BitsPerSample, i));
_capture.Initialize();
```

I found that `WasapiLoopbackCapture` uses Windows' default device unless changed, and the code was using `DefaultAudioEndpoint` to get the properties of the default device. So I added

```
_capture.Device = captureDevice;
//before
_capture.Initialize();
```

And now the program properly pulls the audio data off of my non-default audio endpoint.

Comment: I have since [modified the original program](https://github.com/BLARGoMATIC/KeyboardAudioVisualizer) to add the ability to change between audio devices. I was able to use the `MMDeviceEnumerator` to create a `MMDeviceCollection` to cycle through using a `ComboBox`. Which I'm assuming was the original idea behind the API.

Answer (score 1):

I had been asked to solve a similar type of problem this week. Although there are a few librarys to do this I was specifically asked to do this for "non ish" programmers so I developed this in PowerShell.

[Powershell default audio device changer - Github](https://github.com/WHumphreys/Powershell-Default-Audio-Device-Changer)

Maybe you can alter it to your needs.